# (J2ME) How do you retrieve device color depth in a midlet?

Tags: java, colors, java-me, midlet

how can i determine the color depth of the display device during runtime. is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Call [Display.numColors()](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#numColors()).